# Unit Of Work not work properly in aspnetboilerplate app-service

Tags: entity-framework, transactions, entity-framework-core, aspnetboilerplate

Work on aspnetboilerplate, have following kind of code in app-service, Unit Of Work not properly worked after delete if error raise, without executing the unitOfWork.Complete() data already deleted from the database.

```
 using (var unitOfWork = _unitOfWorkManager.Begin())
            {
                //delete all items in db....
                var response = _grouppermissionRepository.HardDelete(p => p.GroupId == groupId);

                foreach (var item in pageGroupPermissions)
                {
                    if (item.IsChecked == true)
                    {
                        var grouppermissionObj = new Entities.Setup.GroupPermission()
                        {
                            CompanyId = null,
                            GroupId = item.GroupId,
                            IsActive = true,
                            IsDefault = true,
                            IsDeleted = false,
                            PageId = item.PageId,
                            Permission = item.Permission,
                            TenantId = 2
                        };

                        groupPermissions.Add(grouppermissionObj);
                    }
                }
                _grouppermissionRepository.GetDbContext().AddRange(groupPermissions);

                unitOfWork.Complete();
            }
```

Comment: What's the implementation of HardDeleteAsync? From what you're saying it must be comitting the transaction. Why would you expose and use the DbContext from the repository to add permissions instead of having a repository method to do this?

Comment: HardDeleteAsync implemented in Abp.Domain.Repositories just used it for hard delete. As per ABP documentation for batch transaction need to use DbContext with the repository. Stuck on one issue after hard delete, when raised error then unitofwork failed to rollback the deleted records.

Comment: How would you know if the delete records are committed to database without calling unitOfWork.complete() ?

Comment: @ryan.c  after delete just set the return; statement so inserts and unitOfWork.Complete()  statement are not executed but data is already deleted from the database they are not rollback.

Comment: You should await the hard delete async method

Comment: @ryan.c sorry for the syntax mistake, fix the syntax but data are not rollback.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce it with abp template? https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Templates

Comment: After creating template from  https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Templates , face this problem. Maybe my code-share helps to understand what happened. How to share code? create template two months ago.

Comment: @shamim Create a repro project that is forked from [aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template).